# OpenCV Videocapture Grab and Retrieve

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, video-capture

I've had this issue for a long time and I'm not sure whats going on.
So i have a loop from which `nextFrame` is called, now the issue lies with what the `imshow` actually shows.

I specifically want one image every time i call `cap.grab()` and `cap.retrieve()`, but it seems to have this buffer internally in the "cap" object, so instead on getting individual instantaneous images i would get a sequence/images of images when i click through the images, then after 3/4 frames a new sequence.

How do i get single frames?

cap is a VideoCapture object, maxCount is the size of the vector.

```
void CamLoop::nextFrame() {
.
.
.
    //if first loop fill a vector<Mat> with random Mats from camera
    if (firstLoop) {
        Mat buff;
        cap >> buff;
        for(int i = 0; i<(maxCounter); i++) {
            buffer.push_back(buff);
        }
    }

    projector.nextCode();

    if (!customImages) {
        cap.grab();
        Mat buff;
        cap.retrieve(buff);


//tried this way too
//cap >> buff;

        buffer[counter] = buff;

        setMouseCallback( "Camera", mouseFunc, this );
        imshow("Camera", buffer[counter]);
        waitKey(1);
    }
.
.
.
counter++;
}
```

I am using Linux Mint Rosa with OpenCV 3.1.0 on Eclipse Mars

**EDIT**
 The problem is that VideoCapture has a buffer, try this on your own computer in debug mode, the frames aren't live, how would i over come this issue?

I tried using

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,1);
```

but it gives me this error.

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: setting property #38 is not supported
```

also tried

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_MODE,1);
```

but it gives me this error.

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: setting property #9 is not supported
```

**EDIT**
It may be the camera with the buffer and not the VideoCapture object itself.

Comment: What is `maxCounter`? Where do you increment `counter`? Anyway, `cap >> buff` should give you one frame into `buff`.

Comment: Clone the buffer after you capture it. CV::Mat doesn't do a deep copy by default, so you've got a ton of references to the same underlying array (read the documentation)

Comment: edited question, cloning the buffer doesnt help .

Comment: A.Sarid the problem is more that there seems to be this weird buffer in VideoCapture so the image 'cap>>buff' would give me isnt the next frame from the camera, its from this strange buffer

Comment: are you sure the buffer is in VideoCapture and not in your camera? For me there is only 2 buffered images afair.

Comment: I dont know how would i find this out?

Comment: try different video capturing libraries. On windows you could test VideoInput Library. Not sure about Linux. Maybe try VLC player with single step.

Comment: its this common, i think the camera is the problem, it happens on my macbook air too =/ how do i get round this issue?

Comment: use better cameras with their own SDK like point grey cameras.

Comment: or try to change capture mode of your camera: https://books.google.de/books?id=5rntCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=camera+driver+buffering+single&source=bl&ots=lE-aDBOyGG&sig=q6GZ-Artf2yORu3ruBlbjpbLHJM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifmamFl-zMAhXmJ5oKHdAxDcUQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=camera%20driver%20buffering%20single&f=true

Comment: try "still capture mode" for example in https://opensource.com/life/16/1/getting-started-qtcam-linux-webcam ... and please add @micka in the comment so that I get an activity message in stack overflow

Comment: @Micka how does taking pictures one qtcam help? I mean it works on still capture mode, but how do i tell opencv to do this?

Comment: you must tell it to the driver. OpenCV doesn't allow many cam settings, so maybe you can't use openCV there. If QtCam is open source you might be able to adapt that and write your own image gettet class. Or maybe on linux you can programmatically change the capture mode and use openCV afterwards?

Comment: maybe you get some hints here: https://m.reddit.com/r/computervision/comments/2k8lre/opencv_difference_between_capturing_stills_and/

Comment: @Micka feel free to submit this conversation as an answer and ill be happy to accept it. Turns out this is a bigger problem overall, although i may not have the time to solve the problem it is worth to the community acknowledging this can occur.

Comment: Is it an IP camera? or is it a USB camera? or a video file? with an IP cameras and a video files you have indeed buffer effects like you described

Answer (score 0):

A slow and cheat fix may be to do

```
cap.open( *CAMERA_NUM* );
```

in the loop, this is slow but it achieves still images without the buffer.